# Redirect to a different page based on role in a database

Tags: php, mysql, redirect, authentication

I'm new to PHP. I'm trying to create a login page that will redirect to different pages based on their roles. they will login with staff id and password.

Below are my database

Staff_id   password   Role

XXX         XXX        XXX

My HTML login page ---> Login.html
My php code for login --> Login2.php

I've seen other questions n solutions but I still can't get it right. When I log in, it just direct me to an empty page -xx/xx/Login2.php'. What did I do wrong?

I'm using PHP 5.**.

These are my php code:

```
// Connect to server and select databse.
$db= new mysqli("$host", "$username", "$password");

//check connection
if ($db->connect_errno) {
printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $db->connect_error);
exit();
}

// username and password sent from form
$staff_id=$_POST['staff_id'];
$password=$_POST['password'];

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$staff_id = stripslashes($staff_id);
$password = stripslashes($password);
$staff_id = mysql_real_escape_string($staff_id);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);

$sql="SELECT ROLE FROM $tbl_name WHERE STAFF_ID=$staff_id and PASSWORD='$password'";

$rslt= $db -> query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count= $db -> affected_rows;

// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row

if($count==1){

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($rslt, MYSQLI_ASSOC);


 switch($row["ROLE"])
{
        case 'ADMIN':
        header("location: /test/HTMLPages/Admin-register.html");   
        break;

    case 'MANAGER':
    header("location: /test/HTMLPages/View-report.html");
    break;

    default:
    echo "Wrong staff ID or password";
}
}
?>
```

Know that I take others code and patch it up as logically as I can.

EDIT: Fixed. of course it would go nowhere because i didn't state the database name. :D

thank u for ur time :D

Comment: are you sure you're getting your expected result from sql?  You could try `print_r($row);` before your switch to see what you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you select ROLE but as you saied you wrote Role in the DB, you need to write the SAME way you wrote the atrr in the table, and like Fred saied in the comments, it goes the same way in the $row['Role']

```
switch($row["Role"]){

}
$sql="SELECT Role FROM {$tbl_name} WHERE STAFF_ID={$staff_id} and PASSWORD={$password}";
```

i dont know if you not included $tbl_name, but from the code above it seems like you have no $tbl_name variable